# Generate a Spotify API Access Token using Micropython and urequests

Tags: python-requests, spotify, micropython

I'm trying to generate a Spotify API access token using Micropython and urequests on my Raspberry Pi Pico. I tried it with Python3 and it worked fine.

My code with Python3:

```
import requests

# URL and Header
url = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token'
headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Basic my authorization'
}

#Data for the formular
data = {
    'grant_type': 'refresh_token',
    'refresh_token': 'my refresh_token'
}

# execute HTTP-POST-Request 
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)

# handle answer
if response.status_code == 200:
    # Erfolgreiche Anfrage, JSON-Antwort verarbeiten
    json_response = response.json()
    print('Token:', json_response['access_token'])
else:
    print(f'Fehler bei der Anfrage, Statuscode: {response.status_code}')
    print('Antwort:', response.text)
```

This is my micropython code:

```
import urequests
import ujson

base64_auth = 'Basic my authorization'  

token_url = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token'

data = {
    'grant_type': 'refresh_token',
    'refresh_token': 'my refresh_token'
}

headers = {
    'Authorization': base64_auth,
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}

response = urequests.post(token_url, data=data, headers=headers)
response_data = ujson.loads(response.text)


access_token = response_data['access_token']
expires_in = response_data['expires_in']

print("Access Token:", access_token)
print("Expires In (Sekunden):", expires_in)
```

When im trying to use the Micropython´s urequests library, i get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 38, in <module>
  File "urequests.py", line 184, in post
  File "urequests.py", line 123, in request
TypeError: object with buffer protocol required
```

Has anyone an idea what the problem is? I can't figure it out :(